# Config file Ignite discovery in zeppelin, config xml not working even after IgniteConfiguration bean is present

Tags: apache-zeppelin, ignite

I am using zookeeper based discovery for ignite cluster and ignite nodes are getting properly connected.

When i am setting same config.xml file in zeppelin ignite interpreter in , I am not able to run the ignite. it fails with below exception.

It gives me below error on zepplin:
    Failed to find configuration in: file:////tmp/shared.xml 
    Failed to find configuration in: file:////tmp/shared.xml

Exception details: [please click this link](http://pastebin.com/raw/LhacukWt)

ignite_client.xml i am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>

    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.zk.TcpDiscoveryZookeeperIpFinder">
                    <property name="zkConnectionString" value="zookeeper:2181"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="testcache"/>
                <property name="startSize" value="10"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I saw the Ignite code and found that its failing because spring bean is not found of type IgniteConfiguration, but in xml it is actually present as can be seen in shared xml above.

**Analysis so far**

1. Debugged zeppelin and Ignite code and verified correct xml file is passed to ignite.start
2. Verified even content of file tobe double sure by reading inputStream and file content is correct , inputStream is from org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader#loadBeanDefinitions(org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource)
3. On further debug verified that beanDefinitionMap in ApplicationContext contains IgniteConfiguration, attaching snapshot

[image]

4. Tried getting bean by name , it works ... instead of cfgMap = springCtx.getBeansOfType(cls); in org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl#loadConfigurations(java.net.URL, java.lang.Class, java.lang.String...)
5. For sake of trial I used sprintContext.getBean(), assuming it would run, but its getting weired , I got below class cast exception

[image]

After analysis so far, only thing I can understand is some how IgniteConfiguration loaded by diff classloader is causing issue, but dont know why its happening

**Debugged further and confirmed, it is because IgniteConfiguration loaded by different class loader, one loaded already was from sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader#AppClassLoader and in sprinContext IgnitConfiguration bean present is loded by scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader and that is why the error "Failed to find configuration in: file:////tmp/shared.xml" 
Logically I can think it as spark program is scala code and spring bean loaded at runtime that is why this mismatch 
Is this normal ?**

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems that `TcpDiscoveryZookeeperIpFinder` wasn't found during Spring context initialization because it optional dependency.

Comment: I could be the cause, I will try again after adding ignite zookeeper jar also

Comment: i just checked, I already have corresponding jars present

Answer (score 0):

I tried your configuration and it works for me. Did you have another version of the file before? If so, I think it was not updated properly, because the only way to get this exception is having valid Spring XML file, but without `IgniteConfiguration` bean.

Are you sure you actually use the correct file? Can this be caused by the fact that you have it in `/tmp` folder?

Comment: Configuration works for me as well, that problem I face is when I use this same config in Zeppelin interpreter, file I am sure using correct one, but not sure about /tmp folder , I will try it with other location

Comment: If it's reproduced only with Zeppelin, then I'm pretty sure something is wrong with the file there. Zeppelin interpreter doesn't do any magic, it just invokes Ignite API to start a node.

Comment: Right, to analyze further I started zeppelin in Debug mode and debugged Zeppelin and Ignite both code, I verified that file passed is correct, but still no beans found from xml (which I found strange as spring code used, also looks fine) , To verify the content of file I took printed the content reading from inputStream also and file content is ok (Attaching relevant stuff in above post)

Comment: can this be solved with some configuration , to specify specific class loader somewhere for ignite ?

Comment: Why do you think it's a class loading issue?

Comment: I debugged the code and found the exact cause , so the IgniteConfiguration already loaded is from sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader and the one loaded in sprintContext is from ScalaClassLoader , and that is why when  **cfgMap = springCtx.getBeansOfType(cls);** is called it don't find any bean and **throw new IgniteCheckedException("Failed to find configuration in: " + cfgUrl);** is thrown, I also updated the question above with all these details

Comment: I above comment I am refering to code in org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl#loadConfigurations(java.net.URL, java.lang.Class<T>, java.lang.String...)

Comment: I think the problem is Ignite instance created by `IgniteInterpreter`. After it this instance injected into Scala REPL instance and as result we have different class loaders. Need to dig into `SparkInterpreter` in order to understand how to resolve class loader correctly.

Comment: It's known Scala 2.11 issue . See comment here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1738?focusedCommentId=15787430&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15787430 

Will try to find workaround.

Comment: It seems that bug will be fixed soon: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1972